# How to count the number of time a random number is generated in a less cumbersome way?

Tags: c++, random

If a program should simulate a dice roll, and roll the dice any given number of times. How can a code be written, so it could count the times a number was rolled? I have a code below, but I think it's a tedious and ugly method to accomplish this task. I think there is a better way to do this, perhaps a very less cumbersome code.
here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int roll, s1 = 0, s2 = 0, s3 = 0, s4 = 0, s5 = 0, s6 = 0, i, roll_times = 0;
    std::cout << "How many times do you want to roll the dice?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> roll_times;
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    for(i = 0; i < roll_times; i++) {
        roll = rand() % 6 + 1;
        switch(roll) {
            case 1:
                s1++;
                break;
            case 2:
                s2++;
                break;
            case 3:
                s3++;
                break;
            case 4:
                s4++;
                break;
            case 5:
                s5++;
                break;
            case 6:
                s6++;
                break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "The number 1  was rolled " << s1 << " times." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The number 2  was rolled " << s2 << " times." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The number 3  was rolled " << s3 << " times." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The number 4  was rolled " << s4 << " times." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The number 5  was rolled " << s5 << " times." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The number 6  was rolled " << s6 << " times." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a `std::array<int,6> s;` instead, and use `++s[roll];` instead? (`std::vector<int> s(6);` alternatively).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having individual variables, you can utilize an array of 6 integers. Then make use of the indices in the first for-loop to set your counts. The same idea can be applied to your output to the screen.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int roll, i, roll_times = 0;
    int dice[6] = {0};
    cout << "How many times do you want to roll the dice?" << endl;
    cin >> roll_times;
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    for(i = 0; i < roll_times; i++) 
    {
        roll = rand() % 6;
        dice[roll]++;
    }
    for(int k = 1; k <= 6; k++)
    {
        cout << "The number " << k << " was rolled " << dice[k-1] << " times." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why could they be error prone? could you explain by giving an example?

Answer (score 1):

Make yourself a `std::array` which contains the counts. Then, whenever a number appears, you increment the specific count. For example:

```
std::array<unsigned, 6> numberCounts;

numberCounts.fill(0);

for (int i = 0; i < rollTimes; ++i)
{
    ++numberCounts[rollDice()];
}

// Print numberCounts
```

Please note: `std::array` is available since C++11.

Comment: `std::vector<int>` would work as well, if used properly.

Comment: Yes, for pre-C++11, but I'd prefer `std::array` since its size is immutable.

Comment: `std::array<whatever, 6> numberCounts{0}` works without the need to `fill`

Answer (score 1):

i would use an array, something like that:

```
 int counts[6] = {0};
 for(i=0;i<roll_times;i++) {
    counts[rand()%6]++;
  }
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you are right, i am too C-ish, for a more C++ like solution follow one of the other answers. they are all using the same approach (more or less). for example this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27970517/3403216

Answer (score 0):

OK I think a less tedious way to do this is to create an array of size 6, and then add 1 every time a number is rolled and is equal to the index number of this array, but because array indexes in c++ are zero based, all I have to do is subtract 1 from the rolled number. for example when program rolls 1, 5 times, it is added to array[rolled number - 1]  or array[0]. so I wrote a much better code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int roll = 0, i = 0, roll_times = 0,roll_repeat[6] = {0};
    std::cout << "How many times do you want to roll the dice?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> roll_times;
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    for(i = 0; i < roll_times; i++) {
        roll = rand() % 6 + 1;
        roll_repeat[roll - 1]++;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        std::cout << "The number " << i + 1;
        std::cout << " was rolled " << roll_repeat[i] << " times.";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post properly formatted code here.